# Get index number of CoreData at List in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to get an index number of Coredata at the list.

Here is my current code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems:FetchedResults<ToDoItem>
    
    @State private var newTask = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                TextField("new Task", text: $newTask)
                
                Button(action:{
                    
                //saving event title
                let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                toDoItem.title = self.newTask
                    
                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                    self.newTask = ""

                })
                {
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
            
            
            List{
                
                ForEach(self.toDoItems) { toDoItem in
                    HStack{
                    Text("\(toDoItem.title!)")
                        
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        
                        print("Print current Index")
                    }
                }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

I tried to use solutions at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842214/how-to-get-row-index-in-swiftui-list), but keep getting this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults<ToDoItem>' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
```

So I tried to use a loop statement to check all CoreData elements until the same name is matched, but problem was user can have multiple CoreData items with same name.

Would be there anyway to get the index number of CoreData at List?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57244880/10005005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible approach

```
ForEach(self.toDoItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    HStack{
        Text("\(toDoItems[index].title!)")
        
    }.onTapGesture {
        
        print("Print current Index: \(index)")
    }
}
```