# How can I make a numbered, maneuverable list in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Currently, I create a generic list as follows:

```
List {
    ForEach(viewModel.categoryItems) { category in
        Text("\(category.category)")
    }.onMove { indexSet, newOffset in
        viewModel.categoryItems.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: newOffset)
    }
}.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem {
        if viewModel.categoryItems.count > 0 {
            EditButton()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to number this list and also have those numbers change on move (2 becomes 1 if moved into the 1 place).

Answer (score 1):

Give your Category Item a `nr` property. Then in `.onMove` after the move itself just renumber, e.g. like this:

```
struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var nr: Int
    var category: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var categoryItems = [
        Category(nr: 1, category: "alpha"),
        Category(nr: 2, category: "bravo"),
        Category(nr: 3, category: "charly"),
        Category(nr: 4, category: "delta"),
        Category(nr: 5, category: "echo")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(categoryItems) { category in
                    Text("\(category.nr) - \(category.category)")
                }.onMove { indexSet, newOffset in
                    categoryItems.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: newOffset)
                    // renumber
                    for i in 0..<categoryItems.count {
                        categoryItems[i].nr = i+1
                    }
                    
                }
            }.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    if categoryItems.count > 0 {
                        EditButton()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one option would be to use the `indices` property of the array. Something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.categoryItems.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                Text("\(idx) - \(viewModel.categoryItems[idx].category)")
            }.onMove { indexSet, newOffset in
                viewModel.categoryItems.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: newOffset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Downside is that you have to access the object via the array as you only get the current index within the loop.

Some more elaborate solutions are listed here: [How to get row index in SwiftUI List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842214/how-to-get-row-index-in-swiftui-list)